# CAPL block node from sending messages

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I have a CAPL file attached to a CAN node that periodically sends a message using the 'output' function. How can I use a second CAPL file to block the node sending the message (while doing everything that the node does) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an output filter to your node, as shown below, to block the messages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can stop all your cyclic messages, by canceling timers of Each message

Example:

```cpp
message can1.0x12 message1;
msTimer tmessage1;

on timer tmessage1
{
  output(message1);                 // sending message
  setTimer(tmessage1,100);          // set the cyclic time as 100ms
}


on envVar envmessage1
{
  if (getValue(envmessage1) == 1)
  {
    setTimer(tmessage1,100);        // set and start the cyclic time as 100ms
  }
  else
  {
    cancelTimer(tmessage1);         // cancel the cyclic timer 
  }
}
```

if you just do `envmessage1 = 0` in another node, it will stop the message, like the same for all messages, have to write environment variable, then you can control other Node messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sysvar in your simulation, which will be used as a switch in your simulated `*.can` Network node.

You just have to **condition** the output code to the value of the system variable you created.

```cpp
if (Sysvar_SimEnabled)
{
  output(message);
  output(message1);
  output(message3);
}
```

This `Sysvar_SimEnabled` will be a global variable, thus can be set to any value from another `*.can` CAPL Network node.